# HorizontalScrollView Maintain Position In Next Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a HorizontalScrollView with multiple ImageButtons and so far this looks great because I can scroll through my buttons however I would like to click a button (eg: ImageButton 7) which takes me to Activity 7 where I would like the HorizontalScrollView to remain in the same position scrolled from previous activity and not reset to original position after changing activity.

So in simpler terms I would like to get position of HorizontalScrollView and perhaps use intent to pass the values to next activity and then set those positions in that next activity. Hope I am making sense.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsv);


    // btnFeatured
    hsv.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Get the button.
            ibSeven = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSeven);
            ibSeven.setImageResource(R.drawable.ib_seven_h);
            ibSeven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySeven.class));


                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make two variables to save `X` and `Y` position of scrollView

```
public static int scrollX = 0;
public static int scrollY = -1;
```

override `onPause` and save the position like here

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();
   scrollX = hsv.getScrollX();
   scrollY = hsv.getScrollY();
}
```

Then inside `onResume` move the scrolling point to the saved state,

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
   hsv.post(new Runnable()
   {
     @Override
      public void run()
       {
       hsv.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
        }
     });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using intents to switch between activities while maintaining position of scroll between activities, very useful answer, it put me on the right direction. Thanks

Comment: For orientation changes you can do the same in `onSaveInstanceState` and  `onRestoreInstanceState`... Its my pleasure...

Answer (score 0):

Activity 1:

```
scrollX = hsv.getScrollX();
scrollY = hsv.getScrollY();

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySeven.class);
intent.putExtra("value_scrollX", scrollX);
intent.putExtra("value_scrollY", scrollY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 2:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
final int scrollX = intent.getIntExtra("value_scrollX", 0);
final int scrollY = intent.getIntExtra("value_scrollY", 0);

hsv.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


            hsv.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
        }

 });
```